# Reduce size of Java Spring app by removing not needed dependencies or replace starters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring with Gradle to build a restful API. Since this API works with a PostgreSQL 
database I'm also using JPA to connect and interact with this database. I used [this spring.io guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) to develop the basic app and to be able to use JPA I added some more dependiencies. In total the app is now 29MB in size which is a bit too big to my taste. The API features so far nothing more complex than a few basic CRUD actions so I tried to reduce the overall size by:

- Using the [gradle lint plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin) to handle my unused dependencies automatic but running `gradle buildJava fixGradleLint` returns with

  > Task :fixGradleLint
  >   Passed lint check with 0 violations; no corrections necessary
  >   Corrected 0 lint problems
- in the gradle build file I added a configurations block where I used the exclude group or module on unused dependencies like:

  ```
  configurations {
      implementation {
          exclude group: 'org.yaml', module: 'snakeyaml'
          exclude group: 'net.bytebuddy'
          exclude group: 'org.objenesis', module: 'objenesis'
          exclude group: 'org.mockito'
         // exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
      }
   }
  ```

This had the effect that for example *Mockito* disappeared from the dependency listing offered by `gradle dependiencies` but their excludes did not reduces the size of the app at all.

How is it possible to reduce effectively the size of the app? Maybe I can get rid of the spring-starters, because they seem to pull in everything including my coffee mug ;). However, I did not find a way how to do so. I will be happy for every disappearing MB.

Below I posted my `build.gradle` file for clarifications:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE'
    classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:gradle-lint-plugin:latest.release'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'nebula.lint'

gradleLint.rules =  ['dependency-parentheses','unused-dependency']

bootJar { baseName = 'name' version =  '0.1.0' }
repositories {mavenCentral()}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

configurations {
    implementation {
        exclude group: 'org.yaml', module: 'snakeyaml'
        exclude group: 'net.bytebuddy'
        exclude group: 'org.objenesis', module: 'objenesis'
        exclude group: 'org.mockito'
        //exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
     }
 }
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.0.7.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.6.RELEASE'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
 }
```

Comment: You cannot just exclude dependencies. also your dependencies are a bit messy (and why is 29Mb to big?). You cannot exclude `objenesis` as that is needed to create instances of beans. The test dependencies (mockito and byte buddy) aren't part of the packaging so excluding them will only break (or make it harder) to test your application. You shouldn't have `spring-web` etc. as a dependency as those are pulled in by the starters. Also the `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` isn't need for the `SpringBootServletInitializer` that is just part of Spring Boot.

Comment: Hello. Yes this dependency setup is a bit trial and error. I managed to develop a quite complex API with RoR which used 8 MB (all external libraries included), so thats why i would like to reduce the app size. Not adding `spring-web` will have no effect, since the dependency is resolved the starters. How can i break down the starters into the stuff i need? If i check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.0.4.RELEASE i see the dependencies but how can i evaluate which ones are useful for me? I

Comment: The starters only include the stuff you need nothing more. Also comparing apples and oranges with comparing Spring Boot and RoR. Including `spirng-boot-starter-web` will only bring in `spring-web`, `jackson` and `tomcat` nothing else. You did it here manually so basically gained nothing.

Comment: Well i m aware that RoR and Spring are not really comparable but since i only want a restful api out of spring it think it should somehow be possible to strip down the overall size.

Comment: Then all you need is `spring-boot-starter-web` and everything in there is basically mandatory (unless you don't want JSON you could exclude jackson). But everything else isn't optional. Apparently you want JPA to you could use plain JPA and forgo the `spring-data-jpa` dependency but that won't gain you much. So imho you are looking to optimize things you shouldn't be optimizing. What is your concern with the "large" sizes?

Comment: Since i started using hibernate/jpa the app got considerable larger and my local hardware has now quite some trouble starting and running the app. So that is one reason. The other one is that i do not like using big libraries for solving "small" tasks without knowing too much about them.
It seems to me, that i am then doing something wrong, or i dont know the system well enough (which is true after all) to properly use it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you take a look at the insides of the generated JAR files, you'll see that most of the dependencies are mandatory.

#### Changing the servlet container

There are a few options though, while Tomcat is lightweight, Jetty and Undertow are a bit more lightweight, with Undertow being the smallest. This will only allow you to win a few 100 kilobytes though, but you can replace them by excluding the following (using Maven):

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

After that, you could include the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However, on my system this reduced the JAR size about **0,2MB**, not really a big difference.

#### Removing logging

While the Logback framework is included with `spring-boot-starter-logging`, it isn't mandatory. For science, we can by adding the following exclusion to all Spring boot starters:

```
 <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

On my system, this reduced the JAR size by about **1MB**.

#### Removing Tomcat's WebSocket support

If you decide to stay with Tomcat, you could remove WebSocket support if you don't need it. You can do this by adding the following exclusion:

```
 <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

On my system, that reduced the JAR size with about **0,3MB**.

#### Removing support for bean validation (JSR-380)

If you are not going to use bean validation in your API, you can exclude it from your web starter using the following exclusion:

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

This will reduce the JAR size by another **1MB** on my system.

#### YAML support

If you're not going to use `application.yml`, you could additionally remove the snakeyaml dependency by adding the following exclusion to all your starters:

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

This will reduce the JAR size by another **0,3MB**.

#### Removing Tomcat's expression language

Another dependency you might not need when developing simple REST API's is Tomcat's expression language. You can exclude this from the web starter using:

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

On my system, this reduced the JAR size about another **0,2MB**.

---

#### Summary

Summarized, all dependencies that these libraries include are necessary to make them work correctly. If not, they usually provide them as optional dependencies and are very well documented.

It could just so happen that you don't need that functionality. However, this is a risky path, since there's no official guidelines telling you may need this dependency or not, and it could change over time, or you might need that functionality after all.

Typically, the gains are quite small since the large JARS (hibernate-core, tomcat-embed-core, jackson-databind, spring-web, spring-core, ...) are all mandatory.

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for something like this!!

Comment: You cannot have no logging... Excluding `spring-boot-starter-logging` will still do logging but eventually either fallback to System.out or Java.util.logging.

Answer (score 3):

David Syer has created a Thin Launcher for Spring Boot

For discussion and background info,
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1813

Link to project,
https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-thin-launcher

From the project README,

> How does it Work?
>
> Inspect the app jar that you built (or one of the samples in this project) and notice that it is only a few KB. It is just a regular jar file with the app classes in it and one or two extra features. The things it needs to operate are:
>
> The ThinJarWrapper class has been added.
>       Either a pom.xml and/or a META-INF/thin.properties which lists the dependencies of the app.
>
> When the app runs the main method per the manifest is the ThinJarWrapper. Its job is to locate another jar file (the "launcher"). The wrapper downloads the launcher (if it needs to), or else uses the cached version in your local Maven repository.
>
> The launcher then takes over and reads the pom.xml (if present) and the thin.properties, downloading the dependencies (and all transitives) as necessary, and setting up a new class loader with them all on the classpath. It then runs the application's own main method with that class loader. The pom.xml can be in the root of the jar or in the standard META-INF/maven location.
>
> The app jar in the demo is built using the Spring Boot plugin and a custom Layout (so it only builds with Spring Boot 1.5.x and above).

You could also take the approach of using the `autoconfigure` dependency instead of the `starter` which tags all dependendcies as `optional` meaning you *must* provide them yourself. The starter takes the autoconfigue and builds a fat jar with the set dependencies.